# Manual mipmap generation is not allocating the image with the size I give it

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

I create several levels of a mipmap byy calling this in a loop

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, numLevels - 1, GL_RG16, 5, 5 , 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (ByteBuffer) null);
```

and I set these parameters for the texture

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
```

I then attach them in order to an fbo and draw on them. They are now filled with different colors for each texel so it's easier to see the texels when I render them.

I render each of the levels to the screen with a full screen textured quad, alternating the levels with

```
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, testLevel);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, testLevel);
```

The result is that, one of the levels has 5 pixels, the others don't. They have like 3 2 or 1 pixels, or none at all, meaning it just show a black screen.

Why can't I choose the size of the mipmap level? It seems to have a mind of it's own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't choose the size of each mipmap level in OpenGL. Each level has width and height that are half the size of the previous level, rounded down if the size is odd, and with a minimum value of 1. The maximum level is reached when the size of a level reaches 1 x 1.

For example, if the base level is 0 and has dimensions 27 x 17, the sizes of the levels are:

level 0: 27 x 17

level 1: 13 x 8

level 2: 6 x 4

level 3: 3 x 2

level 4: 1 x 1